# Why i am not able to run app on different network(iOS 11)

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9-beta, xcode9

Hi i am able to run app on same network properly but not able to run app on different network on xcode 9-Beta version, i just curious to know why its not possible on different network?

Can anyone have idea over this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about wireless debugging.

The reason is that if you are using a different network, the data transfer will be slower and there would be more lag. When running on the same network, the data does not actually need to be transferred over the internet, just between devices.

This type of technology is similar to what is used by AirDrop and AirPlay, both of which require both devices to be on the same network.